# Type is not convertible to T using generics in Swift

Tags: generics, swift

I've come across an interesting use case. The code is very simple:

```
protocol MXKTabBarDataSource {
    func createTabAtIndex(tabIndex: Int) -> MXKTab
}

class MXKTabBar<T: MXKTab>: UIView {
    private var tabs = [T]()

    var dataSource: MXKTabBarDataSource?

    private func createTabs() {
        if self.dataSource != nil {
            for tabIndex in 0..<2 {
                // getting a compiler error here saying: 'MXKTab is not convertible to T'
                self.tabs.append(self.dataSource!.createTabAtIndex(tabIndex))
            }
        }
}

class MXKTab: UIView {
    var title: String?
}
```

I wonder why that is. Tab bar constraints T to MXKTab, and the return type of createTabAtIndex is MXKTab as well.

Anyone knows what the problem is and how to fix it? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is MXKTab? is it a class or a protocol or? More concretely, in what way are you trying to constrain your class?

Comment: MXKTab is a class. I've updated the code to reflect it. I want the tab bar to flexible, so that anyone extending the MXKTabBar class has the ability to use a custom tab class that derives MXKTab without casting.

Answer (score 1):

If `MXKTab` is a class, then your declaration here says that `MXKTabBar` can be created with any subclass of `MXKTab`. You are calling a method on your data source which (I presume) returns a `MXKTab` object. However, if you instantiate an `MXKTabBar` with some subclass of `MXKTab` (say, `MXKPolkaDotTab` then your createTabs method isn't returning `T`; `MXKTab` != `MSXPolkaDotTab`.

What you might want to do is have your datasource *also* be constrained by `T`. Here is some sample code from a playground that achieves what you want without a lot of complaining:

```
class MXKTab {}

class MXKSpecialTab: MXKTab {}

protocol MXKTabBarDataSource {
    typealias TabType

    func createTabAtIndex(tabIndex: Int) -> TabType
}

class SpecialTabDataSource: MXKTabBarDataSource {
    typealias TabType = MXKSpecialTab

    func createTabAtIndex(tabIndex: Int) -> TabType {
        return MXKSpecialTab()
    }
}
```

Essentially you have to specify your TabType in your implementing class.

(a worse idea would be to cast whatever your dataSource returns to `T`, which might work in practice but isn't something I'd recommend in theory.)

It isn't entirely clear to me that this is an appropriate place to be using optionals,  but I'd need to see more code to really get a sense for that.

Comment: I think I have a better understanding of the issue now. It's true that if you extend MXKTab class and try using it with the MXKTabBar class, then the createTabAtIndex method in the data source protocol will have an incompatible return type. I am looking for a way to say that both the tab bar and the data source must deal with the same tab class. Parameterizing the data source protocol is a good idea. Sadly, the compiler emits the following error: "Cannot specialize non-generic type 'MXKTabBarDataSource'".

Comment: you need to update your protocol declaration. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hey cmyr. I tried it. The compiler complains again. This time it's saying the following: "Statement can not begin with a closure expression". This error is appearing straight on the protocol definition line. I've re-factored my code to not use generics in the protocol functions. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: yea sorry my code was bad, did it in a hurry. I'll update in a sec